# javascript change font size

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

Good day to all,
Sorry if you find this question dumb. Can anyone please help me on how to change the font of the printed output? They said .style.fontSize but I don't know to how use it in that code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="display-date">
        <script language="javascript"> 
        today = new Date();
        var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var day = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        var yr = today.getYear();


        if(yr < 1900) yr += 1900;
        document.write(today.getDate() + " " + month[today.getMonth()] + " " + yr);
        </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who is 'they,' in context? And did you consider asking them what that would involve?

Comment: In the internet. I just googled some of it but no idea on how to use them. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
document.getElementById('display-date').style.fontSize = '2em'; // or whatever measurement.
```

And, because I had a few moments, here's a function:

```
function fontSizeChange(elem, factor) {
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        factor = factor || 2; // 2 is the default
        elem = elem.nodeType && elem.nodeType === 1 ? elem : document.getElementById(elem);
        var cur = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).fontSize,
            size = parseInt(cur.replace(/\D+/g,''),10),
            unit = cur.replace(/\d+/g,'');
        elem.style.fontSize = (size * factor) + unit;
    }    
}
```

Call like so:

```
fontSizeChange('display-date', 3);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/).

Or:

```
fontSizeChange(document.getElementById('display-date'), 4);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/1/).

Or (if you want to use the default setting, you can omit the `factor` argument):

```
fontSizeChange('display-date');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/2/).

And, of course, you can shrink thngs too:

```
fontSizeChange('display-date',0.25);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/4/).

You could also, of course, use CSS:

```
#display-date {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/3/).

An updated version that allows the resizing to be attached to a returned element (`document.querySelector()` / `document.getElementById()`) or a nodeList (`document.getElementsByTagName()` / `document.querySelectorAll()`):

```
Object.prototype.resize = function (prop, factor) {
    if (prop) {
        factor = parseFloat(factor) || 2;
        var self = this.length ? this : [this],
            cur, size, unit;
        for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++) {
            var cur = window.getComputedStyle(self[i],null)[prop],
                size = parseFloat(cur.replace(/\D/g,'')),
                unit = cur.replace(/\d+/g,'');
            self[i].style[prop] = (size * factor) + unit;
        }
    }
    return this;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('div').resize('width',3);
document.getElementById('display-date').resize('font-size', 2.5);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/6/).

```
Object.prototype.resize = function (prop, factor) {
    if (prop) {
        factor = parseFloat(factor) || 2;
        var self = this.length ? this : [this],
            cur, size, unit;
        for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++) {
            var cur = window.getComputedStyle(self[i],null)[prop],
                size = parseFloat(cur.replace(/\D/g,'')),
                unit = cur.replace(/\d+/g,'');
            self[i].style[prop] = (size * factor) + unit;
        }
    }
    return this;
};

document.querySelectorAll('div').resize('height',3);
document.querySelector('#display-date').resize('font-size', 0.5);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pjKVm/7/).

References:

- [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` attribute to change the css properties from javascript

```
document.getElementById('display-date').style.fontSize = '2em'
```

Comment: @Boy Karton see my answer once.try this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.write, you can do something like the the following

```
<style>
  .my_style_class
 {
   // add your font styling information here
   font-size: small;
 }
</style>
<div id="display-date" class="my_style_class">        
</div>

<script>
   document.getElementById("display-date").innerHTML = your_function_which_gets_the_date();
</script>
```